# Converting an HTTP request to a SOAP request

Tags: java, spring, http, rest, soap

I have a program (call it programA) which runs as a Windows service on the local machine that intercepts any requests to port 80 and does some additional work with the request before forwarding the request to the web server/application server.

I have an application server running a Sring MVC application (programB) on another server which serves pages which will be viewed on the same machine as programA is running. The same application server has a web service (programC) running that can accept SOAP messages and returns SOAP requests.

Now what i would like to do is generate a SOAP message using the following sequence of events.

```
Step 1 - User loads the GUI application (programB) on the browser.  
Step 2 - User selects a link on the page which results in an HTTP request to be generated. 
Step 3 - On its way out, the HTTP request is intercepted by programA and formatted into a SOAP message and forward the request as a SOAP request to the web service (programC).  
Step 4 - The web service(programC) processes the request and returns the SOAP response back to programA.  
Step 5 - programA formats the response and returns it back as an HTTP response back to programA as the response for the original HTTP request for it to be displayed on the GUI.
```

programA and programC are existing applications which are already in place so i just need to develop the MVC GUI and the `HTTP --> SOAP` and `SOAP --> HTTP` interfaces.

The main areas i am struggling with is Step 3 and Step 5. Specifically what format the data will be from programB to programA will be.

programA is a java based application can accept any text based format and can be configured to understand most common formats (XML,URL Parameters etc) or can be updated to support another format (e.g. Json).

The main questions i have are as follows:

- What is the most common way of sending the request from programA as an HTTP request to programB so that programB can generate a SOAP request.
- XML is probably the easiest format for programA to handle but is it possible to send an XML as part of an HTTP request? I am thinking Javascript but is there a cleaner way instead of manually building the XML text?
- The request can include name=value parameters in each link. These can be used by programA but again it doesnt sound clean enough.

What are your opinions and what format would you have used?